# How to Import Google Cloud Storage Client libraries into Android Studio, class names rendered RED

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-storage

I have an app running the uses Endpoints and has an app running on the cloud.

I downloaded the Google Cloud Storage client libraries and created a "lib" directory in my project tree (/src/lib)

I copied the .jar files into the lib directory

When I import classes all the classnames are rendered RED in the Android Studio

```
`import com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsFileOptions;
import com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsFilename;
import com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsInputChannel;
import com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsOutputChannel;
import com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsService;
import com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.RetryParams;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalBlobstoreServiceTestConfig;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig;
import com.google.appengine.tools.development.testing.LocalServiceTestHelper;`
```

How do I get the classes recognized?  How can I get the IDE to see the classes I copied into the src tree?

thanks
-a

Comment: UPDATE ANSWER;  in build.gradle file for the project add dependencies like this:

dependencies {
compile files('lib/appengine-gcs-client-0.3.jar','lib/appengine-gcs-client-0.3-sources.jar' )
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}

then "Sync Project With Gradle Files", which will cause a rebuild and the class names are no longer red.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio you have to click with the right button in each library and them click "Add as a library".

This will make Android Studio generate the dependencies code in the gradle file and sync.

The gradle will look like this:

```
(...)
dependencies {
    compile files('lib/appengine-gcs-client-0.3.jar')
    complie files('lib/appengine-gcs-client-0.3-sources.j‌​ar') 
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```